# Notify users when question is being edited

Tags: support, feature-request

I have seen a yellow notification on top of the page when I'm writing an answer alerting me that there are new answers to the question and a link to load those new answers. This is really useful to avoid duplicated answers.

Does the same notification mechanism is working to alert you if the question is being edited and refresh its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a question or answer is edited while you are viewing the page, the UI displays a bar along the top of the question that looks like this:

[image: Post Edited]

When you click on this notification, the individual post updates to show the most recent version.